# In Elixir, is there a way to determine if a module exists?

Tags: elixir

As the title states, my question is:

**Is there a way to determine a module exists by its name in Elixir?**

After looking around for some time I came around [this thread in the Elixir forums](https://elixirforum.com/t/how-to-check-if-a-module-exists-how-to-check-if-a-module-has-a-function/581) but is not exactly what I'm looking for. In this thread they mention `Code.ensure_loaded/1`, but I don't think it is quite what I need.

Right now I'm approaching the problem with something as follows:

```
def module_exists?(module_name) where is_atom(module_name) do
  !is_nil(module_name.module_info)
rescue
  e in UndefinedFunctionError -> false
end
```

But I'm not convinced.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "exists" in order to really answer this question.

Comment: @FredtheMagicWonderDog sure! By "exists" I meant if they are defined and accessible during runtime in certain part of the code.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Usually, we just check to ensure a given function in the module is compiled.

```
iex(9)> Code.ensure_compiled?(Enum)
true
iex(10)>
```

You can also check to see if a specific function is definined

```
ex(10)> function_exported? Enum, :count, 1
true
iex(11)>
```

**EDIT**

@Russ Matney as a good point about `Code.ensure_compiled?/1` loading the module.

Here is an approach that should work without any side effects:

```
defmodule Utils do
  def module_compiled?(module) do
    function_exported?(module, :__info__, 1)
  end
end

iex> Utils.module_compiled?(String)
true
iex> Utils.module_compiled?(NoModule)
false
```

Elixir modules export `:__info__/1` so testing for it provides a generic solution.

Comment: I remember looking into `Code.ensure_compiled?/1` but didn't really consider it. I think it is what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Note one side effect here: `Code.ensure_compiled?/1` will also attempt to load the module if it is not already, which may not be desired (depending on the use-case).

Comment: Worth noting (as a corollary of your last sentence) that this only works for Elixir modules, not ex erlang modules.

Comment: **Note**: `Code.ensure_compile?/1` is deprecated since Elixir 1.10.0 (2020-01-27), [as it indicates in the changelog](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.10/CHANGELOG.md#elixir-7).

Answer (score 2):

Since OTP 20 you can use an Erlang function to determine if a module is present. `:code.module_status(Name)` will return an atom that tells you if the module is loaded, docs: https://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#module_status-1

Comment: I tried your solution, but I didn't get the results I expected. Though I have defined a module `MyMod`, `:code.module_status(MyMod)` returns `:not_loaded` while `Code.ensure_compiled(MyMod)` returns `{:module, MyMod}`.

Comment: It's because the question is unclear. My answer assumes you only wish to check if the module has been loaded into memory as part of a normally running app. AFAIK all modules in the compilation path are loaded by default.